# Padrão de saída de leitores de biometria sobre impressão digital

Tags: desempenho, segurança, matemática, formatação

Gostaria de saber as seguintes questões de alguém que já trabalhou com algum leitor biométrico para impressão digital:

- As saídas de leitores biométricos são padrão, ou seja, um leitor
  modelo A de uma marca X segue o mesmo padrão de um leitor B de marca
  Y?
- A saída é gerada em texto, com um tipo de hash imposto por este padrão (caso exista), ou é algum formato de imagem?
- Se é um hash, é feito pelo próprio hardware ou preciso de uma API
  para gerá-lo?
- Existem diferentes tipos de resolução (dimensões) para os leitores no mercado?
- Eu consigo processar essa saída em um Hardware menos potente? (minha ideia é utilizar em uma [Intel Galileo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Galileo)) .

Comment: Trabalhei (faz basteante tempo) em um projeto que utilizava biometria. • Provavelmente vai precisar de um SDK, com isso, não vai se preocupar com tipo de saída, apenas comparar o valor lido com o valor gravado (no banco ou onde quer que seja). • Não lembro que tipo de valor eu gravava no banco (se não me engado era do tipo blob) • Quanto melhora a resolução mais preciso será o resultado da leitura, lembro que quando utilizada definia o nível de tolerância no SDK, então, quanto melhor a resolução, mais precisa a comparação. Se quiser se aventurar com [API-Windows-C++](http://goo.gl/I2ySxI)

Comment: • Esse tipo de equipamento tem `Padrões de Conformidade`, por isso, penso que leitores (desde que tenham a mesma resolução) do `modelo A marca X` tem o mesmo resultado (leitura) de outra marca. Pense no seguinte exemplo, você tem dois notebooks com biometria, ambos têm leitores biométricos de marcas diferentes. O que acharia se não conseguisse logar em um deles por problemas de biometria? ;)

Comment: @HStackOverflow tem alguma API pra linux ? Vamos tentar implementar isso em uma placa Galileu, que terá um Linux instalado, porém tanho a necessidade de usar alguma coisa com poucas dependências.

Comment: Não tenho experiencia com Linux, porém, uma rápida procura encontrei [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint) Se procurar melhor talvez encontre algo que se encaixe melhor no seu cenário.

Comment: Olá. Sugiro editar a pergunta para deixar claro também no texto (hoje só tem a informação no título) de que a sua dúvida é a respeito de leitores biométricos para impressões digitais. "Leitor biométrico" apenas pode se referir a muitos tipos de medições, que dificilmente seguirão o mesmo padrão porque são leituras distintas (por exemplo, leitura da íris, da digital, da face, da pose do corpo, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu trabalhei com alguns modelos como o DigitalPersona e o PalmSecure da Fujitsu.
Todos vem normalmente com um interface para integração. Ao qual normalmente, possuem implementação para Java, C++ entre outras linguagens.

As saídas de leitores biométricos são padrão, ou seja, um leitor modelo A de uma marca X segue o mesmo padrão de um leitor B de marca Y?
R: Sim, eles possuem um padrão. Como meu caso por exemplo, eu utilizava dois leitores com apenas uma implementação.

A saída é gerada em texto, com um tipo de hash imposto por este padrão (caso exista), ou é algum formato de imagem?
R: Normalmente um array de bytes, porém, possível convertê-la em uma imagem.

Se é um hash, é feito pelo próprio hardware ou preciso de uma API para gerá-lo?
R: Sempre necessitará de integração com SDK(API) deles.

Existem diferentes tipos de resolução (dimensões) para os leitores no mercado?
R: Não sei lhe dizer, mas creio que sigam um padrão nas dimensões.

Eu consigo processar essa saída em um Hardware menos potente? (minha ideia é utilizar em uma Intel Galileo).
R: Depende no que você quer dizer em processar a saída. Se consiste na captura da biometria e enviar para o servidor para processamento, beleza. Porém, se você quer armazenar de forma local no Intel Galileo e processar diretamente nele, creio que será impossível.

Espero poder ter ajudado.

Obs: essas minhas informaçoes são baseadas em estudos que fiz sobre esse assunto há uns 2 anos. Talvez esta área tenha evoluído, fazendo com que estas respostas não sejam tão coerentes nos dias atuais, porém, acho muito improvável, pois trabalhei durante 12 meses e nunca vi mudanças.

Boa sorte!